# How to search directories in home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, shell

I want to find all dot directory in home directory

```
 find  ~/ -name .*    -Olevel 1
```

But it can not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your shell is expanding `.*`. You want to quote it instead, i.e. `'.*'`, so that `find` deals with it instead of your shell.

For example, to find all directories in your home directory,

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*'
```

on my system, this produces:

```
/root/.config
/root/.java
/root/.cache
/root/.aptitude
/root/.gnupg
/root/.grails
/root/.dbus
/root/.ssh
```

Comment: Thanks , there is warning "find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments."

Comment: You probably have a different version of `find` than I do, as I don't receive that error. I've amended my post—it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -type -d
```

You have to stop the shell from expanding the `.*` by putting `'` around it then find then expands `'.*'` correctly. To find only directories use the `-d` switch and to limit find to the `~/` directory use `-maxdepth 1`.